# fedex integration failed in magento

Tags: magento, ssl, magento-1.7, fedex

In magento i integrated fedex with specified details

In my var flder there have a file with name as : shipping_fedex.log

And it have errors are:

```
   [result] => Array
        (
            [error] => SSL support is not available in this build
            [code] => 0
        )
```

What i do now?

In shipping method only `flat rate` displayed ,there have no other options .
.

So what is the problem in magento appplication.....

Iam testing in my local system...

And if there is any ssl support for fedex shipping in magento?

Comment: you said you are working on your local system. how can SSL work in local?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta, ok, i will check it on live server.....

Comment: @KalpeshMehta yes i solved this in live server....

Comment: @KalpeshMehta ,refer this one `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496461/usps-not-working-magento-1-7-ce` and try to find a solution......